# NSUserDefaults Chance UISwitch Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

i have a 2 different view settings view and default view

i can't pass uiswitch value to default view

Switches stores position in NSUserDefaults

settingsview.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"SwitchState"])
        self.BlowSwitch.on = [defaults boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];

}

- (IBAction)saveSwitchState:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if  ([self.BlowSwitch isOn]){
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SwitchState"];
        //[defaults synchronize];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SwitchState" object:self userInfo:nil];
    }
    else{
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"SwitchState"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SwitchState" 
                                                            object:self userInfo:nil];
    }
}
```

defaultview.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onAppSettingsChanged:)                                                                          name:@"SwitchState"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) onAppSettingsChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL completed = [defaults boolForKey:@"SwitchState"];

    if (completed == YES) {
        //bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `onAppSettingsChanged:` is being called?

Comment: switch enabled work fine but switch disabled nothing ever changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't execute `[defaults synchronize]` when checking `[self.BlowSwitch isOn]`, remove the comment and try again.